# Closing a Rare Window using Pywinauto

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I have a very long script that processes files and one the rare occasion, Internet Explorer, not related to the main program, will pop up. I need to close it before I move on to the next steps.

I have tried using `app1 = Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re=".*Internet Explorer")` and then `.wait('enabled')`, `if` statements, `time.sleep(20)`, blah blah blah. This window doesn't always show up and because of this, I get the `ElementNotFoundError`, and my code stops.

How can I close the Internet Explorer window when it pops up about a fraction of the times I run my code?

Comment: Why would Internet Explorer open if your code doesn't tell it to and you don't tell it to?

Comment: Why not just catch that error and ignore it?

Comment: The program uses a website to process data, and if it cant connect to the website, it opens Internet Explorer to explain the connection issues.